# Permissions : I don't need user informations

Tags: permissions, facebook

I have just a quesition about facebook api.
I use this code to know if the user is logged on Facebook :

```
FB.init({appId: '**********', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: false});
```

I don't ask permissions. But when I redirect the user with this script :

```
if (!response.session) top.location = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=********&redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/my_apps/";
```

the user is redirect to the Permission Asking page...  But I don't need personnal informations in my application, I just need to verify if the user is logged on Facebook, and redirect it on login page. After he can use my application without permissions. maybe it's impossible... ?

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the user's permission before you can get his login status. Search for login using facebook and use it.

Some facebook components like "Like Button" will have iFrame from facebook, So it can access user's facebook details.